# Best Graphdrawing library

Tags: graphics, graph, diagram, diagrams

I have some data that has X and Y values and i would like to print them in a graph. I don't need anything advanced because the data is very simple but I would like something that looks good and has nice design (which excel hasn't).

Thanks for any help

Comment: And its Java, one more thing that came up in my head is that I dont want the simpliest graph. The thing is that the X values are months in time. And then each month I have several different objects with different values. Example: Month 2 I have 3 apples, 2 pears and 5 bananas and I want the graph to show this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net) (cross-platform GPL plotting library) is rather simple to use and produce nice plots -- see [samples](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/en/pictures.html).

Comment: Thank you, I also found JFreeChart which is very nice!